# Sporadic "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run a Java executable through the command line.

First I go to the directory the executable is located at and execute the following:

`java -cp .;JARNAME-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar main.class.name`

This is a packaged jar so it does not have any `.class` files.

However, this command sporadically throws the `Error: Could not find or load main class main.class.package.name` error message.

Does anyone have any suggestions to get to the bottom of this?

Thanks

Comment: jar contains .class files.

Comment: what do you mean "This is a packaged jar so it does not have any .class files"? Where are class files?

Answer (score 0):

Last argument is **class** name, not package name

Comment: Thanks talex, that was an error, I do have the main class name.